# Unable to move jQuery Spinner buttons vertically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do some styling on top on the jQuery spinner that's set up like this:

```
<span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="height: 14px;">
<input id="testSpinner" class="ui-spinner-input" name="value" aria-valuemin="9" aria-valuemax="1550" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton" aria-valuenow="9"></input>
    <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr" tabindex="-1"></a>
    <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br" tabindex="-1"></a>
</span>
```

I'm trying to stack the two buttons, but I'm unable to move the "up" button up and the "down" button down. I'm able to move the down button left by overriding the `ui-spinner-down` class and setting `margin-left: -3.2rem`, but `margin-top` / `margin-bottom` aren't working.

jQuery sets the `height: 14px;` in the `span` tag, so I'm having a hard time fiddling with that as well.

Currently:

[image: Current implementation]

Desired:

[image: Desired implementation]

Comment: Do you have a live link with this? It would help to see what's happening there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` instead of `margin-up` and `margin-down`

To override the `style` attribute, you can set the height with "!important"

```
height: 10px !important;
```

If `margin` doesn't work, you may want to instead try `position: relative; top: 10px` where "10px" gets adjusted to make the button position itself in the desired spot.

Make sure you also set appropriate `padding` or `line-height` to get the arrow centered in the specified height.

Another note - you'll want to adjust jQuery's `border-radius` to 0 on the right side of the input and left side of the buttons.  And you'll want make `border-left: 0` on the buttons and `border-top: 0` on the bottom button

Comment: Oops that was a typo - I was using margin-top/bottom - fixed that in the question. `position: relative; top: 10px` worked!!

Comment: No worries.  A note on why margin may not be working.  Margins only work for block-level elements.  Buttons by default are inline elements, which makes margin an ignore attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generated source from the jQuery spinner example.

```
<span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <input id="spinner" class="ui-spinner-input" name="value" aria-valuenow="6" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton">
    <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button">
      <span class="ui-button-text">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n">▲</span>
      </span>
    </a>
    <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button">
      <span class="ui-button-text">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">▼</span>
      </span>
    </a>
</span>
```

And if you look at the css you'll see:

```
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png");
}
.ui-spinner .ui-icon {
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-n {
    background-position: 0 -16px;
}
```

So it looks like the simplest solution is to override the position of .ui-icon-triangle-1-n (and -s)

Comment: I was trying to move the button itself, but this is very useful for my next step, so thank you!